# Windows 2008 R2 Standard server - how to disable RC4

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, iis-7

I have just used www.ssllabs.com and ran a few tests - my server is capped to a B grade because my server accepts RC4

> This server accepts the RC4 cipher, which is weak. Grade capped to B.

I've researched and found that to disable RC4 I need to add 3 keys, and set their enabled dword to 0 [Link](http://microsoft.public.inetserver.iis.security.narkive.com/QGfNpAtS/disabling-weak-ciphers-and-sslv2-in-windows-2008-iis-7) and [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/a3a3d1e3-95f8-481a-8cef-42e386464be5/how-to-disable-sslv2-and-weak-ciphers-in-windows-2008-iis-70)

I have done this for `RC4 40/128`, `RC 56/128` and `RC4 64/128`

I then restarted my server. When the server was up again, I verified the Registry Changes were done, and they are - all 3 exist and all 3 have their enabled value set to 0.

I return to ssllabs, clear the cache, re-run the test and it returns the same result (capped to B due to RC4 being enabled).

At this stage, I'm not sure what this means - if SSLLabs showing incorrect results (I'm going to assume not), have I disabled RC 4.

How can I tell if I have successfully disabled RC4

**Edit**

I also saw the KB about this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2868725?wa=wsignin1.0 so trying now... I've done the same registry changes but, when I try to download the 64 bit version for W2008 R2 Standard, it fails to install with error message

> The update is not applicable to your computer

Comment: RC4 is currently safe.
If you don't fight security agencies with thousands of servers full of radeon cards, then you have nothing to worry about.
The Cypher4's security problems are a pure speculation at this point.
Microsoft wants to dump it because they just want new standards in exchange.
In a practical sense, even SHA-1 isn't broken yet.

Comment: I'm lost what MS has to do with this - they are not reporting a fault (unless ssllabs.com are owned by MS)? With SHA-1 are you saying it still works but there are more secure options out there?

Comment: MS is using RC4 on the operating systems and want to move away from it. Yes, SHA-1 was created in '95, of course it has evolved, but the point is it is still secure.

Comment: The are several reports that RC4 is not safe: http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2868725-recommendation-to-disable-rc4.aspx

Comment: There is an IETF RFC in the standards track requiring the removal of RC4 proposals from TLS handshakes due to security issues: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7465

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [a tool](http://nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) to check the cipher order in a GUI. It works for me every time. (Try it on a test machine if you don't trust the exe.)

Microsoft released [a security advisory about RC4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2868725) where they explain how to disable RC4 on the client and server side. Now it's best practice to disable RC4.

Don't forget to do the Windows Update in the security advisory because there is a `schannel` update to do **before** updating the cipher order.

When the update is done, you can use [the tool (IISCrypto)](http://nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto), the Microsoft advisory patch, or update the windows registry yourself:

#### (Be careful. Back up your registry first.)

```bat
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 128/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 56/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I didn't even need to run the scan - as soon as I opened it, I saw `RC 128/128` which was not listed in the links I cited. Adding `RC 128/128` and setting the dword Enabled to 0 has fixed the issue.

Comment: @Dave, could you please add an Answer with the info from your comment? It would be very helpful! :)

Comment: @Lizz @Dave, did you mean `RC4 128/128` or is there a separate `RC 128/128`?