# Windows 2008 Server IIS7 Disable RC4 cipher

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5

After an security audit of our Windows Server farm we got this notice:

> Disable support for any RC4-based cipher suites.

The most information I can find is this

[Microsoft Technet Security Advisory 2868725: Recommendation to disable RC4](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2868725-recommendation-to-disable-rc4.aspx)

Does anyone have any further instructions or recommendations beyond this?

Thanks much

Comment: For server software, you have much better chances of getting good answers on [sf] instead. I am voting to migrate this. Please do not repost the same question elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was the place.

Comment: No worries, you could have done worse! It isn't *wrong* to post it here, but it's a *better* fit for Server Fault. Rule of thumb: corporate sysadmin type questions go onto SF, home user type questions go onto SU.

Comment: Thanks, I did not even know about Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

The Server Fault Site has an answer for this. 
[Windows 2008 R2 Standard server - how to disable RC4](https://serverfault.com/questions/669810/windows-2008-r2-standard-server-how-to-disable-rc4)

The real key seems to be to use the [IIS Crypto app from Nartac](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto), which was an app I was apprehensive to install and try on a publicly facing server.